# aws-cli: getting error "argument --user-pool-id is required"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cognito

I am trying to get user information from cognito user pool using aws-cli. According to [aws-cli documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/admin-get-user.html) the **synopsis** should be like this:

```
admin-get-user
--user-pool-id <value>
--username <value>
[--cli-input-json <value>]
[--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
```

I have tried with these:

```
aws cognito-idp admin-get-user us-west-2_MMyZYq4B1 mahbubur.rahman
aws cognito-idp admin-get-user --us-west-2_MMyZYq4B1 --mahbubur.rahman
```

but getting error **aws: error: argument --user-pool-id is required.**
what's wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user-pool-id and username are the option key:

```
--user-pool-id <value>
--username <value>
```

So the command should be:

```
aws cognito-idp admin-get-user --user-pool-id  us-west-2_MMyZYq4B1 --username mahbubur.rahman
```